# Linux password via kerberos unable to reset

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, kerberos

When I try to reset a ldap user password from client machine I am getting the following error

```
$ passwd
Changing password for user demo.
Current Password:
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

From `/var/log/secure`

```
 May 31 15:49:31 host01 passwd: pam_sss(passwd:chauthtok): Password
  change failed for user demo: 22 (Authentication token lock busy) 
 May 31 15:49:31 host01 passwd: pam_krb5[27418]: no password-changing
  credentials for 'demo@LDAPSERVER.NET' obtained, user not known
```

This user exists in ldap server and kerberos database(principal).

Please advise.

Comment: Please edit the contents of `/etc/pam.d/passwd` and its associated includes into your question.

Comment: if you use kpasswd insteadd of passwd? This will change the user password using the kerberos protocol tools.

Comment: Decided to go with out sssd.  All works fine with out sssd. 
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: cat /etc/pam.d/passwd

# cat /etc/pam.d/passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   substack     system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the port 464 (tcp or udp) for the service kpasswd is open in your freeipa server's firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Hexdump's answer helped.

However, in some cases (slow network) it might be helpful to increase the value of krb5_auth_timeout in sssd.conf:

```
krb5_auth_timeout = 60    #Default value is 6 seconds
```

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3609651

(Yes, this is a "paid members only" support site.)